# Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite, and routes.ini for multipaged section

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I have a ZF applications that is using custom routes to a list of pages (say a list of locations) and am having a problem either understanding how their routing reqs value works or the regular expression to make it work. I'd like http://domain.com/locations to go to http://domain.com/location/list/page/1 and then have the following (http://domain.com/locations/2 -> http://domain.com/location/list/page/2, etc...).

The problem is identifying the empty case (ie http://domain.com/locations).

In my routes.ini, I have (which doesn't work but /^[\d]*$/ does work in a simple preg_match):

```
routes.locations-page.route = locations/:page
routes.locations-page.defaults.controller = locations 
routes.locations-page.defaults.action = list-new
;routes.locations-page.reqs.page = \d* - does not work
routes.locations-page.reqs.page = ^[\d]*$
```

What reqex would catch the http://domain.com/locations, http://domain.com/locations/1, and http://domain.com/locations/2 scenarios in a single route?

thx

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to match the URLs http://domain.com/locations and http://domain.com/locations/2 in the same rule because the URL structure is different. But you can try the following to achieve what you want to do.

In your bootstrap file,

```
    $r = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('locations/(*)',
                    array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'list-new'), 
array(1 => 'locationID'));
    $router->addRoute('add-location', $r);
```

You can also use your preferred way of adding routes.

In your locations controller,

```
$locationID = $this->_getParam('locationID');
```

Now, based on this value, forward to appropriate actions.

Comment: hmm... pretty similar to what I have but the regex isn't working for me. You get stuck back in initial situation where you need a 0 at the end. I'm doing an ugly mod_rewrite redirect of locations -> locations/0

Comment: @timpone is "locations/(*)" not matching "locations/"?